# img src not working as expected using JS/JQuery: previous image get displayed instead of new uploaded image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form to upload images. By default the source is `"images/noimage.png"`;

```
<img id="previewing" src="images/noimage.png" />
```

I store the path in the database. If I select a specific user and the form gets loaded I want to display the image for the specific user. I do this in the `windows.onload` event. However another image (previous image the user had, if user had one) gets loaded instead of the new one.

```
var Logo = 'Logos/123.png'; //path stored in Database

if (Logo!='') {
  //If the user has a 'Logo', show it
   $("#previewing").prop("src", Logo);
} else { 
  // if user has no 'Logo', show default image
   $("#previewing").prop("src", 'Images/noimage.png');
}
```

This does not work as expected. What's wrong here?

Comment: This sounds like a caching problem. Try appending a timestamp to the image path. Also note that it should be `window.onload`

Comment: Agree with Rory, try to reload the page with `CTRL + F5`, if the picture changes afterwards it is a caching problem

Comment: yes it changes...

Comment: if url is different for different users, then this is not a caching problem

Comment: @AlexeyObukhov is the same url

Comment: To get a unique URL and avoid caching problems, use: Logo += '?rnd=' + new Date().getTime()

Comment: try `attr()` instead of `prop()`

Comment: @mthrsj `attr()` is what I tried originally but it did not work.

Comment: @AlexeyObukhov this is it, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If after reloading image getting change then most probably its Caching issue.
you may try adding some random string into image URL like

```
Logos/123.png?v=xyz
```